# 3D Animation of Fractals

Tags: python, animation, blender

I'm giving a presentation on Fractal Antennas (take a look at my previous threads) in November and I wanted to incorporate some animation to make my presentation easier to visualize the content I am referring to. Most of these animations would be relatively short, probably a minute long at the most. There are a few animations that would be fantastic to have:

1. Fractal Mountains - The animation continues to add new iterations that depict the complex features of a mountain range.
2. Fractal Koch Curve - The animation begins with an initiator (triangle) and adds new iterations. Either I slowly bring in the new fractal that has the next iteration, or I use the same model and users can see the iterations branching outward. I would prefer the latter technique.
3. Show a fractal. Increase the iteration, while keeping a constant length, to vindicate the fractal shrinking in size.
4. Show a fractal. Increase the iteration, while keeping a constant size, to vindicate the fractal is increasing it's total perimeter length.
5. Cell phone animation - show a cell phone that has multiple antennas popping out (they can be simple sketches of lines).

The trouble is, I've never done ANY animation before. In the programs I have already, they generate the coordinates of the fractals, if that can be of some use?

What is the best way to render those animations in the shortest time possible? The presentation is almost 6 weeks away! Blender might be an option, but I have no idea of how to go about this.

There are some great animations in [this](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/physics/hunting-hidden-dimension.html) NOVA video that might give you an idea of what I'm after.

Thanks,

Austin

Comment: Why can't you use animations on YouTube?

Comment: I thought of that, but I can't find simple renditions of the Koch Curve, for instance. Usually, the animations on YouTube depict complex fractal patterns.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxDi8p5ELWs

Comment: I would like an actual 3D representation of the Koch Curve (not the snowflake), I hope this isn't too hard. Also, wouldn't I have to face copyright issues if I used YouTube?

Comment: No thoughts anyone? I'm thinking that Blender might be the best way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've used VPython to create simple 3D graphics and animations. It's an easy to learn library that's freely available at http://vpython.org/. Since you have the coordinates already, it should be fairly easy to for you to incorporate that into the drawing.

Blender is a bit more complicated, but also incorporates python scripting if you want to spend the time to learn it.

Lastly, referencing some of the YouTube comments: if you use the video just cite it, or email and get permission. If you're not making money on this presentation, then odds are you're going to just fine using the videos.

Comment: After reviewing the basic structure and syntax of the Python library for Blender, I couldn't agree with you more. I give my presentation this Saturday (wish me luck!), and as of yet, I use YouTube videos and also the animation from 4NEC2. I will take your advice and cite my sources.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to use matplotlib.mplot3d. The principle is the same as in the 2D animation described at http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations but you will be using the 3D methods described in http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html.

I teach computer methods in physics and one of the activities is to create a Koch snowflake using Python and matplotlib. I also had a group of students create 3D fractals as their project using Python and Chaco (for interactivity) but using matplotlib instead is pretty straightforward. You can also try mayavi2 which is another 3D plotting library in Python.

If you want to create a movie then you need to save each frame as a graphics file then convert the files into movie using convert (ImageMagick), mencoder, ffmpeg or some other software.

I can probably provide some pseudocode/sample code but I'm too sleepy at the moment (it's 11:30pm from where I am).

Comment: Matplotlib looks great for mathematical development in Python, this is would be a great tool for me to learn about in the future. I would be interested in seeing some example code you have, feel free to post!